# .NET Core 3.1 in linux container: The HTTP request is unauthorized

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core

I have some .NET Core 3.1 code that makes a call to a WCF service:

```cs
     var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://my-url");
     var client = new MyClient(MyClient.EndpointConfiguration.basicHttpBindingMy, endpoint);

     client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("api username", "api password");
     client.GetStuff();
```

Auto-generated code by Visual Studio for the binding:

```cs
    System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
    result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
    result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
    result.AllowCookies = true;
    result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
    result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
```

**Problem**

This works perfectly on Windows, but when run in a Linux container (based on docker image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1`), I get this error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP
> request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.
> The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,
> NTLM'.

**Attempted solutions**

I tried the following solutions I found elsewhere, but they do not seem to make a difference to this:

1. Called in main(): `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);`
2. Added to Dockerfile: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils gss-ntlmssp`

Comment: Please help to share your `web.config` and `app.config` files

Comment: @Ashok I do not have any app.config file. This is a NET Core 3.1 console application.

Comment: Confirmed same problem exists in .NET 5.0

Comment: Since you have found the solution can you remove the bounty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the issue!
It turned out to be caused by external factors, that had corrupted part of the login credentials during de-serialization, so the above code was not even the cause :/

Answer (score 0):

It might be that different SSL protocols are supported/enabled natively depending on the OS.

Try force allowing all available security protocols:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it did not make any difference